# Missing Tooltip for some data points using chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart's which has 200 data points which plots correctly but the tool-tip doesn't appear for the last few data points. Please refer the [jsbin Link](http://jsbin.com/yowokuzoki/1/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the points are so close together their hit raidus is over lapping.

if you add the following property as an option to the graph you should find that all points will be reachable, of course once the graph gets too small even setting this as 1 will not help

```
  pointHitDetectionRadius:1
```

http://jsbin.com/xiconuraqu/1/edit?html,js,output